# Asking for numbers using classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, for-loop

The program should be like this:
1-ask for series and then parallel resistance (different classes)
2-pass Eq_R_Series and Eq_R_Paralel values(after they are calculated) to the Equivalent resistance that will calculate the Eq_R_Total
3-Display the Eq_R_Total.

so i need the main function and 3 classes(1 of the classes needs the info from the other 2).

```
          class Serie
{
private:
    int i, n = 4;
    float R_Eq_S;
    float r[4];
public:
    float serie()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "Resistence " << i + 1 << " ";
            cin >> r[i];
            R_Eq_S = R_Eq_S + r[i];

        }
        return R_Eq_S;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Serie s;
    s.serie();
}
```

So i have the program with no errors now (doesn't mean theres nothing wrong), it runs and asks me to introduce the 1st resistence but after that it doesn't continue the cycle.

(i "just" need help to "link" the class to the main and the principal class.)

so this is my basic approach and it works but this is very limited, with a for i can change the number of resistance with one simple editing.
Thanks guys for the help even if it was just to point my mistakes ;) at least i think i'm learning

```
class Series
{
private:
    float R1, R2, R3, R4;
public:
    float R_Eq_S;
    float series()
    {
        cout << "Resistance1= ";
        cin >> R1;
        cout << "Resistance2= ";
        cin >> R2;
        cout << "Resistance3= ";
        cin >> R3;
        cout << "Resistance4= ";
        cin >> R4;
        R_Eq_S = R1 + R2 + R3 + R4;
        return R_Eq_S;
    }
};
class Parallel{
private:
    float R5, R6;
public:
    float R_Eq_P;
    float parallel(){
        cout << "\nResistance5= ";
        cin >> R5;
        cout << "Resistance6= ";
        cin >> R6;
        R_Eq_P = (R5*R6) / (R5 + R6);
        return R_Eq_P;
    }
};
class Equivalent{
private:
    float R_Eq;
public:
    float r_eq()
    {
        Series s;
        Parallel p;
        R_Eq = s.series()+ p.parallel();
        return R_Eq;
    }

};
int main()
{

    Equivalent r;
    cout<<"\n\nR_Eq= "<<r.r_eq()<<endl;

}
```

Comment: You may want to [edit] your post to take out all the extra white space.  While you're doing that, make sure to tag it with [tag:c++].

Comment: I mean, there's a lot wrong with this.

For starters you're trying to index into `r` but it's just an integer. So you can't do that.

Comment: paralel has three el's.

Comment: @Tyler you're right. in my c version i have r[] but i totally forget here. Thanks

Comment: Well now i don't get any errors but it doesn't execute the class as i wanted to.
It just does nothing. i'm really good at this ;)

Comment: @nicomp my bad, not first language, sometimes some letters will be missing

Comment: and i'm really stupid. i have the private and public statements wrong.
Damn, i'm a c++ god

Comment: @Kriptis class is not "executed" because strange design and not creating an object. I'm not sure You understand how to use classes.

Comment: Classes don't "do" anything; they're not units of execution. They're more like `struct` in C. (And in fact, the `struct` keyword declares a class in C++).

Comment: ... gee, thanks for reverting my spelling/grammar fixes.

Comment: @JacekCz yep, i don't know how much of this works, i'm trying to learn by making the program on my own. i think i need to restart the class part because i'm in the dark.

I'll be back

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler has pointed it in his comment. In your class definition `r` is declared as of type `int`. Then, in the expression `r[i]`, `i` should be a pointer (this is usual C/C++ symmetry: `a[i]` is the same as `*(a + i)` so one of them should be dereferenceable, the other one being a number, but it does not matter much which one which). Your `i` is again an `int` nevertheless.
Second, I don't quite get how can your code compile, `serie` is a private method yet you call it outside of class's context.

Comment: yeah you are right. i noticed that after i correct (i think) the r[] part.

I fix it and i can run the program but only does the first resistence. the loop ends there

Comment: Yes because you `return` in the loop body thus it never goes past the very first iteration.

Comment: f me.. this simple mistakes makes all the difference. thanks
i'm now using a basic approach, asking values one by one and it works.
time to adapt it to the cycle for